# Is it possible to increase Output Field Name length beyond 10 characters?

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

When creating a new Column, the default value for the length of the name is 10. Using the Field Calculator via the Model Builder, I want to include the names of regional areas into the columns which has more than 10 characters.

Can the length of the **Output Field Name** be increased?

Comment: If the attribute size is the most important thing, and not the shapefile, look at saving your data into a spatial database, such as Spatialite.

Comment: @RyanGarnett, thanks for the advice. The attribute size was more for an aesthetic purpose than anything else.

Comment: I have had that issues too. You may want to look at setting an alias. You can do this in the Properties window in QGIS, under the Fields tab. You can set the Alias, and that change will be reflected in the attribute table.

Comment: Use an Alias for such situations

Comment: @Geo.Dude - Thanks, I believe that's what I did at the time :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the output file is a shapefile, it is **not** possible due to the restrictions of the shapefile definition:

http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html

> Attribute names can only be up to 10 characters long

Comment: Looks like the link is 404.Perhaps use this white paper: https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

Comment: @Aaron I updated the link.