# Cannot export using "Save Selected Feature As..." in QGIS because the name is more than 10digits. How to export without manually changing the column

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to export the shapefile that I have to a smaller shapefile using "Save Selected Feature As...". But, the saving process is error due to the length name of the column. How can I export it and get the shapefile without manually changing the column attribute name manually?

[image]

Comment: save to geopackage instead, shapefiles don't allow for column names with more than 10 characters.

Comment: Similar question:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97364/is-it-possible-to-increase-output-field-name-length-beyond-10-characters

Comment: I do not know what QGIS does, but GDAL tries to rename the attributes like this `Successive duplicate field names, including those created by truncation to 10 characters, will be truncated to 8 characters and appended with a serial number from 1 to 99.` Even that system cannot handle more than 100 attributes.

Comment: Shapefiles are also limited to 255 fields (though the spec said 100) and a total of 4000 bytes/row.